# Bingbot request for trafficbasedsspsitemap.xml which does not exist

Tags: bing, logging, web-crawlers

The logs for a website I manage show a request for a non-existent file by Bingbot. The details of the request are

- Path: **/trafficbasedsspsitemap.xml**
- Useragent: "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
- IP address: 65.55.213.244 (reverse lookup resolves to **msnbot-65-55-213-244.search.msn.com**)

What reason is Bingbot looking for this file? What does "Traffic Based SSP Site Map" mean?

Comment: been getting a few of these in the last 24 hours or so in one of my sites, curious too.

Comment: I've been seeing lots of these too

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is Vincent from Bing Webmaster Tools.

This was a Bingbot checking for an XML sitemap generated by the Bing Sitemap Plugin (Beta) for IIS and Apache - see the following for more details:

- [Bing Sitemap Plugin (Beta)](http://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/bing-sitemap-plugin-beta-f50bebf5) - Bing Webmaster Tools Help & How-To Center
- [Building Sitemaps Manually?… Stop Until You Read This!](http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/webmaster/archive/2013/02/20/building-sitemaps-manually-stop-until-you-read-this.aspx) - Bing Webmaster Blog

You shouldn't see this kind of discovery request very often.

Comment: The crawler does not ask the `robots.txt` and it doesn’t look into `sitemap.xml` – it just uses some made-up path again and again? This should be fixed fast.

Comment: I checked one of my hosts and it gets this request once per _minute_. I hope some Bingbot people are able to fix this soon.

Comment: I'm getting this request about once a day per site it seems (with and without "www."), though sometimes twice to the same site within 30 minutes.

Comment: I m also seeing way too many requests of this type in my error_log on the few servers where I havent blacklisted bingbot already . . . well, one more reason to blacklist this buggy bot

Comment: Is there a directive in robots.txt to tell bingbot where this special sitemap is? (or if there are no such special sitemap)